# What's the KDB equivalent of the following numpy code

Tags: kdb

I'm trying pick up more Q so I'm curious about the best way in Q to achieve the following.

> In [18]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>
> In [19]: b=np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4))
>
> In [20]: a Out[20]:  array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
>          [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
>          [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>
> In [21]: b Out[21]:  array([[3, 6, 9, 5],
>          [4, 2, 1, 3],
>          [6, 9, 3, 5]])
>
> In [22]: a[a>5] = b[a>5]
>
> In [23]: a Out[23]:  array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
>          [4, 5, 1, 3],
>          [6, 9, 3, 5]])

Also what's a good way to do,

```
a[np.where(cond)] = b[np.where(cond)]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent KDB operations for your commands are mentioned below.

**NOTE:** Please note that these KDB and numpy functions are not totally
equivalent. They only behave similar for certain input conditions. Read the behavior of KDB functions in detail specially because 
they are highly overloaded.
I have provided the links at the bottom for kdb operators used here.

**1. a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)**

Equivalent of numpy 'arange' with single input in KDB is 'til' operator. And reshape operator in KDB is '#'.

Equivalent KDB command for that would be:

```
 q) a:2 4 #til 12
```

**2. b=np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4))**

'?' operator in KDB gives random values. It doesn't support size but that can be easily achieved using shape operator.

```
q) 2? 4  / output 1 3 (2 random values)
q) 3 4# 12?10
```

Or we could make a generic function for that:

```
q) {(y;z )#?[y*z;x]} [8 ;3 ;4]
```

**3. a[np.where(cond)] = b[np.where(cond)]**

There are different ways to do this in KDB. It depends on your list size which solution to use. Some will perform better
on small list and some will perform better on a big list. So test those according to your project.

All the three solutions mentioned below will give you the output you wanted.

```
q) a: 3 4#til 12;
q) b: (3 6 9 5;4 2 1 3;6 9 3 5)

q) a:(a*not i)+b*i:a>5  /solution 1
```

Using @ and each-both

```
q) a:{@[x;y;:;z]}'[a;i;b@'i: where each a > 5] / solution 2
q) a:@'[a;i;:;b@'i: where each a > 5]  /short form
```

Or change original array in place using dot(.) operator:

```
 q) l:(til count a),'enlist each where@'a>5 
 q) {.[`a;x;:;y]}'[l;b ./:l]  /solution 3
 q) .'[`a;l;:;b ./:l]  short form
```

Read more details here:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/card/

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/arith-integer/#til

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/unclassified/#apply

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/select/#index-at

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/random/#roll

Answer (score 0):

a: 3 4#til 12 // Initialise a matrix as per above logic

b: 3 4# 12?10 // Initialise b matrix as per above logic

@'[a; t; :; b @' t: where each a > 5] // Based on above logic